# using nth-child & not in css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to use css for build page layout. I want it to be as much content independent as possible.

The idea is to have 4 div in each row, and I did it using float:left for all div and :nth-child(4n+1) selector for clear:both. Some divs I want to be first in line (cr before), and i mark its by class="cr", but i want it to have 3 divs after in the same line, before cr (clear:both).

Target is to have:

```
Test Test
Test Test Test Test 
Test Test Test Test
```

Is it possible ?
So far i'm here:
http://jsbin.com/isowab/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is to my knowledge not really possible in pure css (but I would be more than happy to be proven wrong).

If I understand you right ... you want the `nth` count to reset after every `div` of class `.cr`, rigt?

CSS unfortunately does not work that way. Every time you will assign a new `nth` rule it will apply for all elements of a type from beginning. Using the adjacent selector `+` or `~` you could do some of the magic ... for example to start applying the style with the `nth` rule only after the first occurrence of the .cr class

**but there is no way to reset the `nth` counter after each div of class `.cr`**.

You could do this by **adding hierarchical structure** or dynamically by assigning specific classes using **javascript** or **serverside** ... but **NOT** in pure css.

---

**Edit:** For example if you are using jQuery you could add something like this:

```
    var i=1;
    $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('cr') || i%5==0){
            $(this).addClass('cr');
            i=1;
        }
        i++;
    });
```

And in css apply `clear:both;` to the `.cr` class.

Here is this example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ29T/

Comment: Thanx for you answer. I followed hierarchical way before, and wondered whether data could be flat. I was tried selector like: DIV:not(.cr):nth-of-type(4n+1) & DIV:not(.cr)+DIV:not(.cr)+DIV:not(.cr)+DIV:not(.cr)  but it also does not work that way :(

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make those rows explicit? Something like:

**CSS**

```
section > div { display: inline-block; background: green; }
section > div:nth-child(even) { background: blue; }
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
</section>
```

I am using `inline-block` here because it's much simpler but if the gap between elements is an issue, you can float them or [fight the spaces](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: This is the way I find myself... but i want to remove this hierarchy, and apply css presentation to flat data

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
div:nth-child(4n-1){
    clear:both;
}
DIV:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: blue;
}
DIV:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

[click here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Venugopal/TZbtk/)

Comment: I think that this is fixed layout. I want it to be dependent on content, and it is not known where extra new line occurs (if any).
    <div class="cr">Test</div>

Comment: I don't think that is the answer he was looking for. One of the requirements was to have div with floated to the left, with a class of .cr